# How to check if someone has shared my webpage on Facebook?

Tags: javascript, php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can  check shares like this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://amazon.com
```

this will give me a response like

```
{
   "id": "http://amazon.com",
   "shares": 1395576,
   "comments": 14
}
```

Now, after a user has clicked on share button I can again call

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://amazon.com
```

and if share count has increased I will know it has been shared. Is there any other better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can direct the json data display on a web page

Answer (score 0):

You can´t, and this is intended - because it would be able to gate content behind a Share Button, which is not allowed according to the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/):

> 4.5 Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other
>   actions.